# Cambiar background color de un input cuando no este vacio [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Buenas gente.

Estoy tratando que al rellenar un input él mismo cambie su `background-color`,esto se tendria que hacer dinamicamente,sin tener la necesidad de hacer click en un boton o recargar la pagina.
He intentado esto, pero no funciona:

```
function ActiveInputs() {
var gg = $('#search-form').find('input:text,select, textarea').val();

$(gg).on('blur', function () {

    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

¿Álguien me echa una mano?

Comment: Hola, podrías poner tu HTML o un ejemplo de tu código que no funciona, sería mas fácil darte la ayuda.

Comment: sabes como podrias usar esa accion, pero que al detectar el valor vacio del input , cambie el color de un label y un span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías crear una función para modificar el css con jquery y ejecutar directamente a través del evento onchange() por ejemplo:

```js
function cambio(elemento){
  if ($(elemento).val() === "") {
    $(elemento).css("background-color", "");
  }
  else{
    $(elemento).css("background-color", "blue");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <label for="example">Ingreso Texto</label>
  <input type="text" onchange="cambio(this)" id="example" name="example"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Funciono gracias :)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar el selector :input para coger todos los elementos del form.
En el evento change compruebas si tiene valor y, en función de si el valor es vacío o no, le asignas la clase css para cambiar el fondo:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#search-form :input')
    .change(function(){
      var $input = $(this);
      if ($input.val() === '')
      {
        $input.removeClass('filledInputs');
      }
      else
      {
        $input.addClass('filledInputs');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.filledInputs{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-form">
  <input type="text" /> <br /><br />
  <textarea cols="20" rows="4"></textarea> <br /><br />
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
    <option value="3">Tres</option>
    <option value="4">Cuatro</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder :)